# Select elements of Tensor based on index tensor along same dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following two tensors

```
input shape: 16 32 32 3
index shape: 16 32 32 2
output shape: 16 32 32 3
```

The formula for the output would be:

```
output[b, h, w] = input[b, index[b, h, w, 0], index[b, h, w, 1]]
```

I tried to use `torch.gather` but I was not able to formulate the previous assignment.

Does anyone know how to do this in an efficient manner? Thanks!

*For context: input contains a batch of 16 elemens where each one is a tensor of 32x32 that containts 3D points. index is a mapping from position to 3D point.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by unraveling the indices from `index` (on dimensions `1` and `2`) in order to index `input` on a single dimension using [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html).

This requires to expand the shape of the indexer to fit the shape of `input`:

Here is an example with some dummy data:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(16, 32, 32, 3)
>>> index = torch.randint(0, 10, (16,32,32,2))
```

Some manipulation on index is required to unravel the values:

```
>>> unraveled = x.size(1)*index[..., 0] + index[..., 1]
>>> u = unraveled.flatten(1).unsqueeze(-1).expand(-1, -1, x.size(-1))
```

Now `u`, reshaped expanded version of `index` has a shape of `(16, 1024, 3)`.

The indexed tensor also needs to be flattened:

```
>>> x.flatten(1, 2)
torch.Size([16, 1024, 3])
```

Finally, you can gather on `dim=1` (keep in mind the result needs to be reshaped to the desired shape *i.e.* the input's shape):

```
>>> out = input.flatten(1,2).gather(1, u).reshape_as(x)
```